# Calculating closeness centrality using Jung

Tags: java, algorithm, rdf, jung, jung2

I am developing a semantic web application, and using Jung library to apply some graphs calculations, such as closeness, betweenness, etc. I was able to find the betweenness value for each node in my rdf and normalized it too. However, this is not the case with the ClosenessCentrality as I got NaN (not a number) score for some nodes.Below is my code:

```
int n =  graph.getVertexCount();// number of vertex 

double d = (double)(n-1)*(n-2)/2.0d; // this is to normalize the node value 

System.out.println("Applying ClosenessCentrality");

ClosenessCentrality<RDFNode, Statement> closeness = new ClosenessCentrality<RDFNode, Statement>(graph);

double[] closenessValues = new double[n];

Collection<RDFNode> closenessVertices = graph.getVertices();

int i = 0;

for (RDFNode vertex : closenessVertices)

closenessValues[i++] = closeness.getVertexScore(vertex) / d; // get the normalized score for each node

for (double score : closenessValues)

System.out.println(score);  // print all values.
```

So, as I mentioned before for some reason I got NAN score for some nodes. I feel that there is a bug on the ClosenessCentrality algorithm implementation as I got NaN. Any explanation guys ? am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you checked the closeness values before the normalization? NaN can be returned for 0/0 for example.

Comment: Thanks @EyalSchneider, you are right, but my d value which I used to calculate the normalization never got zero value. I did and still got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to recheck the code, but I'll bet that the closeness centrality value may do something weird if the vertex in question appears on no shortest paths (because it's a disconnected vertex or has no incoming edges).  I'd check that first.

Comment: thanks @Joshua O'Madadhain for the reply. Well this is not the case in my graph. My constructed graph that I used for closeness calculation is fully connected (no DISCONNECTED vertex at all). i.e I made sure while constructing the graph that every vertex has at least one edge in and another edge out. Thus, I am waiting for your answer regarding this issue. Above is my code that I used for finding the closeness. FYI: the same code works just fine with betweenness.

Answer (score 0):

if there's no edge to any other node from a vertex, then the closeness centrality of that vertex would be divided by 0.
And NaN is the result. 
That's why you get the NaN for some vetex.

Comment: How should I handle if I get NaN for some vertices?